# String length check appears to not work

Tags: javascript

No-brainer for you but why is this not working in my Javascript document?

```
<script>
prompt("Are you ok?");
 if ("no".length > 3) {
 window.location.href = "http://google.com";
 } else {
 window.location.href = "http://facebook.com";
}
</script>
```

The problem is that even when I type something that is bigger (and smaller) than "no", it takes me to Google. I just recently started with JS and thought that it would be cool if I could add it to my website.

Comment: "no" string vs `no` variable ?

Comment: you're not checking their response, you're just checking the string `"no"`. Which never changes length.

Comment: There's no PHP there, just Javascript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You aren't using the value that is returned by the prompt.

```
<script>
var response = prompt("Are you ok?");
if (response.length > 3) {
  window.location.href = "http://google.com";
} else {
  window.location.href = "http://facebook.com";
}
</script>
```

If you do `"no".length` it simply returns the length of the string `"no"`, which is 2. That's why your condition was always resulting in Google.

Instead, you can get the value returned by the prompt and check the length of that instead. Even better, you can directly check against a specific string.

```
var response = prompt("Are you ok?");
if (response === "no") {
  window.location.href = "http://google.com";
} else {
  window.location.href = "http://facebook.com";
}
```

Comment: Or even shorter: `if (prompt("Are you ok?") === "no")`.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if constant length is greater than its actual length, resulting impossible combination.

```
console.log("no".length) // you'll get always 2
console.log("no".length > 2) // always false
```

The way you should do it (I like one-liners)

```
window.location.href = ('no' === window.prompt('Are you ok?')) ? 'http://google.com' : 'http://facebook.com';
```

Another solid way of dealing with Yes-No answers in browser:

```
window.location.href = window.confirm('Go to Google?') ? 'http://google.com' : 'http://facebook.com';
```

Comment: I don't mind @Barmar ... Edited the post and hope it makes sense to everyone.